# pygal: labels on multiseries pie

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, charts, pygal

How do I add labels on the secondary series of a [multiseries pie chart](http://pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/types/pie.html#multi-series-pie)?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it pass in your values as a dictionary.

First import some of the required packages

```
import pygal
from pygal.style import LightGreenStyle
```

Initialize the Pygal Pie Object. You can ignore the fancy theme (LightGreenStyle).

```
pie_chart = pygal.Pie(width=900, height=500, 
                  style=LightGreenStyle, 
                  value_formatter=lambda x: "{}%".format(x))
```

Here is the part you want.

```
pie_chart.title = 'Wine Quality Percentage'

pie_chart.add('Good Wines', [{'value': wine_quality_8_percent, 'label': 'Quality Rating - 8'}])

pie_chart.add('Average Wines', [{'value': wine_quality_5_percent, 'label': 'Quality Rating - 5'},
                                {'value': wine_quality_6_percent, 'label': 'Quality Rating - 6'},
                                {'value': wine_quality_7_percent, 'label': 'Quality Rating - 7'}
                               ])

pie_chart.add('Poor Wines', [{'value': wine_quality_3_percent, 'label': 'Quality Rating - 3'},
                            {'value': wine_quality_4_percent, 'label': 'Quality Rating - 4'}])
```

Notice that values are passed in as a dictionary with 'values' and **'label'**. This will get your labels in your multi-series Pie.

[image]

this is **similar** to the labels in **regular Pie** -
[Using PyGal, how can I embed a label on the pie chart itself on hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464555/using-pygal-how-can-i-embed-a-label-on-the-pie-chart-itself-on-hover)